# Dynamically load external js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets say I an ajax requests sends a requests to the site with HTML code. If this code has JS code its OK, it runs automatic. But what if that code needs another JS / jQuery code in external file? How to load it?

Comment: [**jQuery.getScript()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

Answer (score 2):

Per @adeneo above:

```
$.getScript('/path/to/my.js', function() {
  //code to execute once script is loaded
});
```

Comment: i like this, but i just realized that i think the question is about getting the remote html's inline JS to execute with it's depends, which requires a bit more than a one-liner.

Comment: @dandavis yeah, when you dynamically load an HTML page the JS will not get executed.  You could get around this by searching the HTML for `script` tags, read their `src` attributes and THEN use this code.  But the OP does say he "need another JS/jQuery code in external file" so the above should be enough.